# How to enable debugging in Node.js application

Tags: node.js

Currently I'm having a lot of `console.log` in my modules. Many of them are debug-messages, which I only need to see, if I'm debugging my application.

I would like to enable debugging using a parameter when starting up my application, for instance `node myApp.js -d`. Further my module should then only call the `console.log` if debugging is active.

What is best practice in Node to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look up npm  [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug). 
I believe that's what you are looking for.

To Install debug:

```
 npm install debug --save
```

example code:

```
var debug = require('debug')('your module');
debug('msg', 'more details');
```

To start debugging all the application run the following:

```
DEBUG=* node myApp.js
```

To debug only a few modules on your app:

```
DEBUG=first,second node myApp.js
```

For no debugging run your app normally

```
node myApp.js
```

Answer (score 3):

Use something like winston , as it provides different logging options. Below is a simple example of something u may need

```
// Require winston logging library
var winston = require('winston');

// Check if -d is present as CLI argument
if(process.argv.indexOf('-d') > -1){
   winston.level = 'debug';
}

// This is only print when winston.level is debug
winston.log('debug', 'Now my debug messages are written to console!');
```